# How do I convert a char to a char-based Enum object?

Tags: c#, enums

I have this enum:

```
enum OptionalityEnum { call = 'C', put = 'P', undefined = 'N' }
```

Is there an easy way to turn a char into the enum type?  This works:

```
char chOpt = 'C';
OptionalityEnum opt = (OptionalityEnum)chOpt; //opt = OptionalityEnum.call
```

But if my char is a value that doesn't exist in the enumeration, this produces weird results.

```
char chOpt = 'X';
OptionalityEnum opt = (OptionalityEnum)chOpt; //opt = 88
```

I know about some of the Enum functions, but I can't find one that does this conversion for me.

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(OptionalityEnum)) = { call, na, put }
Enum.GetValues(typeof(OptionalityEnum)) = { call, na, put }
Enum.TryParse<OptionalityEnum>("C", out optionality) = false

Enum.TryParse<OptionalityEnum>("call", out optionality) = true 
  //... but that's not what I want.

Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OptionalityEnum), "call") = true
  //... but that's not what I want.
```

Do I need to write my own converter?  Something like this?

<strike>private static OptionalityEnum Convert(char ch)
{
    OptionalityEnum result = (OptionalityEnum)ch;
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OptionalityEnum), result))
        return result;
    else
        return OptionalityEnum.undefined;
}</strike>

```
private static bool TryConvert(char ch, out OptionalityEnum opt)
{
    opt = (OptionalityEnum)ch;
    return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OptionalityEnum), opt);
}
```

This works but it seems sloppy.  I'd be surprised if something like this doesn't already exist.

EDIT: I originally used a bad example for my `Convert` function.  I changed it to the `TryConvert` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "sloppy" solution seems entirely appropriate to me. There's nothing else which is going to default to "undefined" for you. Using the conditional operator would make it slightly cleaner:

```
private static OptionalityEnum Convert(char ch)
{
    OptionalityEnum result = (OptionalityEnum)ch;
    return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OptionalityEnum), result)
        ? result : OptionalityEnum.undefined;
}
```

EDIT: For the `TryConvert` method, I'd actually make sure that you set `opt` to `default(OptionalityEnum)` if it doesn't exist.

But no, I don't believe this exists in the framework. However, you might want to look at my [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) project where you could at least use the `IsNamedValue` extension method, which would avoid boxing.

Comment: Ok, I see now that I used a bad example for my Convert function.  Please see my TryConvert function.  It's actually shorter, so maybe it's not that bad.  I'd still be surprised if nothing like this already exists.

Comment: @user2023861: See my edit. I really don't think there's anything like this.